# UI keeps Updating in Debug but without it nothing happens

Tags: java, javafx

I want to populate a table with data.

The following Code are two bits out of the controller, because I sadly don't know which part is important.
Each function is supposed to take an Observable List which was declared in the main phase and clear it out.
Then add new Entries according to the current status of the arrays and in the end use populate() to populate the table with it.

But this sometimes fails. The data is added into the arrays, but it isn't shown in the table.
Has anybody an idea what could be the reason for that?

```
public void showAll() {

    //Clear existing data
    Main.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    //add new data on base of the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < Main.array_anz.length; i++) {
        if (Main.array_pla[i] != 0) {
            Main.data.add(new Article(Main.array_bez[i], Main.array_pla[i], Main.array_gew[i], Main.array_pre[i], Main.array_anz[i], Main.array_kat[i]));
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    //Show the data in the table
    populate();
}





private void populate() {
    ArtikelbezeichnungTable.setCellValueFactory(new 
PropertyValueFactory<Article, String>("artikelbezeichnung"));
    LagernummerTable.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Article, 
Integer>("lagernummer"));
    GewichtTable.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Article, 
Double>("gewicht"));
    AnzahlTable.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Article, 
Integer>("anzahl"));
    KategorieTable.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Article, 
String>("kategorie"));
    StorageTable.setItems(Main.data);
}
```

Comment: Please rewrite your posting so that you provide more information about the context of the question you are asking. Once you have done so, please actually state the question you are wanting an answer for. Reading this posting I have no idea as to what it is you are wanting to accomplish nor do I have any idea as to what it is that is happening instead of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Issues being changed when debugging are often concurrency issues. No way to tell though, since you didn't post a [mcve].